# JProfiler java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, eclipse, jprofiler, unsupported-class-version

I'm want to attach JProfile to a running virtual machine, Weblogic 9.2 (jrockit 150_22) in my case.

In Eclipse 4.4 I'm compiling with JDK 5 ; JProfile Session Setting has /Compilation/JDK 5 ; General Settings JDK 5, JRE 1.8

I had to use an older version of JProfiler, v.7.2.3 specifically, because was the only one with jrockit 1.5 option.

I followed these steps to create a new Profile:

```
Session/Integration Wizards/New Server Integration/...
```

To attach to the running Weblogic VM I press the button "**Attach JProfiler to a running VM**" on Eclipse and select the vm from the popup window on JProfiler.

But I'm always getting this error:
[image: this error]:

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel This is not a duplicate, as the environment/tool is different. The fact is that JProfiler 7, "_Attach functionality is only supported for Oracle JVMs with version 6 or higher._" , from the [docs](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/jprofiler/help/doc/#jprofiler.profiling). And the OP has jrockit 5

Comment: @tomyforever The underlying problem is the same: it is trying to use/load a class that was compiled for Java 6, and therefor it won't work with Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) the classversion 50.0 corresponds to Java 6 - that does not match what you configured in JProfiler.